# "Dopplung" von Worten/Sprachelementen = "Wiederholung" oder "Dublette"?

Tags: style, terminology

Auf der Suche nach der korrekten Schreibweise des Begriffs „Dopplung“ stieß ich auf die Wikipedia-Seite dieses Begriffs. 
Dort stellte ich fest, dass die Bedeutung dieses Wortes wie ich es bislang in meiner Alltagssprache benutzt habe, keine Erwähnung findet: **ein (meist als unschön empfundenes) doppelt verwendetes Wort/Sprachelement.**

Bezeichnet man die wiederholte Nennung eines Textelements in der deutschen Sprache eher als „Dublette“? Oder kann man in einem Dokument bedenkenlos den Begriff „Dopplung“ verwenden?

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopplung

Comment: Kannst Du ein Beispiel geben, wie Du "Dopplung" verwendest?

Comment: Vergiß Dublette, das hat nichts mit Wiederholung zu tun. Dublette ist ein Fachbegriff in verschiedenen Bereichen. Im Englischen  sind Wörter wie porc und pig Dubletten,  das eine Wort kommt vom Französischen, das andere Wort ist heimischen Ursprungs.

Comment: @Robert: zuletzt in einer Formulierung für Redaktionssystem-Handbuch. Dort sollte der Begriff die Anweisung ausdrücken, Artikel nicht in zweifacher Ausführung innerhalb der Website auftauchen zu lassen. Da die Wahrscheinlichkeit einer mehr als doppelt auftretenden Wiederholung rapide abnimmt (nur zwei Redakteure pflegen Inhalte ein), wollte ich das Wort „Dopplung“ an dieser Stelle verwenden und mich vergewissern, dass es nicht „Dopplung“ lautet ;-)

Comment: „...dass es nicht _Doppelung_ lautet“ wollte ich eigentlich schreiben

Comment: "Bitte Artikel nicht mehrfach einstellen." tut es nicht?

Comment: "Das Duplizieren von Inhalten sollte vermieden werden" (um zumindest ein ähnliches Wort zu verwenden ;-)

Comment: @hellcode das klingt super. Ich glaube, „Duplikat“ passt in diesem Zusammenhang am besten

Comment: Hm, das ist ja eine ganz andere Problematik als die eigentliche Frage vermuten ließ.

Comment: @TehMacDawg 9: das genannte Beispiel ist vielleicht ein wenig irreführend. Hatte ich aufgrund der Aktualität gewählt. Es geht mir lediglich darum, ob es in der deutschen Sprache einen feststehenden Begriff für doppelt auftauchende Begriffe/Wortkonstrukte etc. gibt

Answer (score 2):

Wenn es um ein Wort für das stilistische Problem des *zu nahen Aufeinanderfolgens* des gleichen Wortes oder der gleichen Phrase im Text geht: **Wiederholung** (repitition). Im Deutschen wird unnötige Wiederholung als stilistisch ungeschickt empfunden, wenn es nicht gerade gezielt als rhetorisches Mittel eingesetzt wird. Das ist weniger dramatisch z.B. bei technischen Texten, wo Knappheit, Klarheit und Unmissverständlichkeit Vorrang haben, oder bei Texten für Kleinkinder.

Diese Art der Wiederholung wird z.B. durch Wortwahl und Benutzung von Pronomina und Synonymen vermieden:

> Als **Mandy** in die Kneipe **ging**, grüßte **Mandy** den Wirt und **ging**
>   schnurstracks zur Toilette. 
>   
> → Als Mandy die Kneipe **betrat**, grüßte **sie**
>   den Wirt und ging schnurstracks zur Toilette.

Bei "Dopplung" denkt man eher an eine absichtliche zweifache Ausführung, z.B. "Oh!" → "Oh, oh!" ; "s" → "ss"... "Dublette" lässt eher an eine einzelne Kopie als solche oder eine weitestgehende Gleichartigkeit von etwas denken.

Answer (score 0):

Sprachwissenschaftlich ist Dublette bereits doppelt besetzt, s. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublette):

> semantische Dublette, siehe Synonym
>   etymologische Dublette, siehe Verwandte Wörter

Answer (score -1):

> keine Erwähnung findet

doch, hier:

> deutet stets auf eine Zweiheit hin

Wikipedia hat keinen Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit. Solche Listen verschiedener Bedeutungen haben auf Wikipedia auch oft den Zweck, verschiedene Artikel zu unterscheiden.

Die Suche nach *Zweiheit*, führt übrigens zu [dieser Seite über Dualität](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dualit%C3%A4t), deren Abstammung so erklärt wird:

> von lateinisch *dualis* „zwei enthaltend“

Es ist auch gar nicht sinnvoll, alle Dinge aufzulisten, die doppelt vorkommen können. Das sind nämlich relativ viele. Das gilt für alle Wörter, die irgendwie Mengen ausdrücken. Bloß weil im Artikel zu Dutzend keine Hühner erwähnt werden, heißt das ja auch nicht, dass man nicht zwölf Hühner kaufen/schlachten/sehen/etc. kann.

Wikipedia beschreibt die Realität, nicht anders herum.

Wenn aus deinen Äußerungen mit Dopplung nicht klar zu erkennen ist, ob es dir um Wörter, Blechfalze oder reparierte Schuhsohlen geht, dann stimmt daran etwas im Allgemeinen nicht. Wörter stehen in einem Kontext. Erst aus dem Kontext wird klar, welche von mehreren Bedeutungen des Wortes verwendet wird.

Comment: ich bin mir nicht ganz sicher, warum deine Antwort ein Downvote erhalten hat… Die Erwähnung des Wikipedia-Artikels ist nicht der Kern meiner Frage, sondern sollte lediglich darauf hinweisen, dass ein Lexikon jene nicht eindeutig beantworten kann. Ein Beispiel kannst du weiter oben unterhalb meiner Frage lesen. Wenn ich dich richtig verstanden habe, wäre in dem genannten Beispiel die Verwendung des Wortes „Dopplung“ also richtig.